# Is it faster to filter by multiple columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has the following columns

```
Id         (int)
UniqueId   (string)
CategoryId (int)
```

Id and UniqueId are unique for each record.

I want to find a record based on `UniqueId` value, and i also have the `CategoryId` value.

Is it faster to specify both filters in the `SELECT` statement, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM [Products] Where [UniqueId] = 'product' AND [CategoryId] = 4
```

Or should i just use the `[UniqueId]` filter?

The table has a lot of records

**EDIT :**

I don't have the `[Id]` column of the product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest,Just create a non-clustered index on uniqueid and just use that field as filter

Comment: -1 The index should be on `UniqueId` and `CategoryId` and filter should be on both. We can't assume that there is a `UNIQUE` key on both `Id` and `UniqueId`

Comment: OP has alraedy mentioned that both id and uniqueid are alwayas unique then why you think he should use both as filters which will create more load on performance?

Comment: Using a less selective `WHERE` clause, as you're suggesting, causes overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to use unique id filter that will do the thing, also don't forget to put an index on UniqueId to make your filtering faster.

I prefer putting index on the columns i want to filter(used in where clause).

Answer (score 2):

That will depend on if you have an index on the table, and which columns the index include, and the actual order of the index.

if you had an index with columns `(UniqueId, CategoryId)` with the appropriate included columns set, your query should be fine.

Adding the other required columns in the included columns will then avoid a key lookup to retrieve the columns in your select.

That is also why you should almost never use `SELECT *`

Your best option would be to look at the Execution Plan, and try avoiding any table scans/key lookups

Have a look at something like [Execution Plan Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's faster to filter on which column is indexed.

And if they are both indexed I think it's faster to filter on only one column because for each  column filter the server has to do processing that will take time.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any indexes, then

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Products] 
WHERE [UniqueId] = 'product'
```

If you have an index on any of the columns, then use that column in the `where` clause.

If you have index on both `UniqueId` and `CategoryId` then your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Products] 
WHERE [UniqueId] = 'product' AND [CategoryId] = 4
```

is fine

Answer (score 0):

Just filter on `Uniqueid`. SQL server won't even look at the other columns, because a unique index provides the fastest sort (O=log2N)

Answer (score 0):

First of all

pull **only the columns** that you want to pull

I believe, you have [CategoryId]   has cluster index. So  you should pull record using filter [CategoryId]. Don't use Product filter

you query would be

```
SELECT * FROM [Products] Where  [CategoryId] = 4
```